# How to pipe a cat output to stdin?

Tags: c++, mail-command

C++ -------> g++ -------> bash :

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    system("mail -s test_mail xxxx@testdomain.com");
    system("test msg");
    system(".");

    return 0;
 }
```

The first system command runs fine, but then it's like it takes input from another input stream (not stdin). system("test msg") only runs after i cntl+c out of the mail program, only then does bash try to interpret "test msg".

Comment: `system` is not intended to act like a way to inject stuff like it is coming from stdin.  It runs whole command lines.  Write your message to a temporary file, then do something like `system("mail -s test_mail xxxx@testdomain.com < tempfile.txt");`

Comment: You're looking for `popen`, not `system`, as you need to write to mail's stdin. Or possibly the much more complicated fork/pipe/dup2/exec combo. But you probably ought to ask your programming questions on [so].

Answer (score 1):

`system()` really just runs command lines.  Its not a pipe like thing.

The smallest possible change to make your example program work would be

```
int main()
{
    system("echo test msg | mail -s test_mail xxxx@testdomain.com");
    return 0;
}
```

because then your message is going into `mail` program standard input via a pipe.

More practical would be for you to write your message to a temporary fle, and then redirect `mail` stdin from that file

Comment: infixed:  I tried piping it like that but it sends the content as an attachment, not as the email *content*.

I also tried the "< tempfile.txt" method but that also sends it as an attachment.

(i've yet to try derobert's suggestion i'll get back to you after I try it)

Comment: That would seem to be non-standard behavior for the usual unix `mail` program.  This sort of question has come up before, and the stdin solution was given as one answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36500/6047952  I'd suggest doing a `man mail` and seeing if your version has some switch that can control it to .  behave as you wish.  You are sending just simple ASCII stuff, right?

Comment: lol dunno, how can I check?

Comment: The simple ASCII bit is import.  For instance look at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136493  where anything but printable ASCII and linefeeds ( no returns!) becomes attachments.  This is probably what is happening to you.  That `echo text | mail yourself` should be simple